# C++ error with functions as parameters, initial value of reference to non-const must be an lvalue

Tags: c++, function, pointers, lambda, reference

So, here is the part of the code in relation to the error:

```
Array Array::transform(std::function<int(int)>&f)
{
    std::for_each(niz, niz + n, [&f](Tacka &r) {r.setX(f(r.getX())), r.setY(f(r.getY())); });
    return *this;
}

Array Array::operator+=(const int a)
{
    return transform([&a](int b) { return b + a; });
}
```

The error appears when trying to send a lambda function as an argument.

If I remove a reference from "transform" function parameter, the code works. But I don't understand why it didn't work in the first place.
How can I fix the code without removing a reference from parameter?
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You call your method transform and pass the object of the type `std::function` as an expression that creates a temporary object of a lambda type.

```
return transform([&a](int b) { return b + a; });
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You could declare the parameter like

```
const std::function<int(int)>&f
```

to avoid the message.

A temporary object may not be bound to a non constant reference.

Comment: Thank you. Why can't a temporary object be bound to a non constant reference?

Comment: @A6SE Think about what happens when the temporary object gets destructed. What is the reference now referencing?

Comment: Does the temporary object get destructed immediately, even before the transform method finished its job?

Comment: @A6SE A temporary object is not lvalue.

Comment: @A6SE Compare for example the following code. void f( int &x ) { ++x; } f( 3 ); What is the sense to change the integer literal?

Comment: Ok, I think I got it. If I declare the parameter without reference, the copy of the temporary object which I send as argument will be made on that method call, so the method will be using the copied object and will work with it fine. But, If I have a reference parameter, it will be using an original argument, which gets destructed before the method even enters its body, so it doesn't have an object to work with anymore. Did I get it right?

Comment: @A6SE To avlid copying of objects it is better to use const reference.

Comment: Oh, I think I missed something. What does a const reference parameter do with an rvalue argument to keep it from destroying itself? How does ti differ from non-const reference parameter?

Comment: @A6SE The question is not about destroying an object. The question about a potential possibility to change a temporary object using a non-const reference.

Comment: Oh, and that is because changing a temporary object doesn't make sense, right?

Comment: Changing a temporary make sense if you receive a rvalue-reference. The syntax look like this: `std::function<int(int)>&&`. That way you can have a mutable reference to an rvalue. But lvalues are not permitted when you do that.

Answer (score 1):

```
Array Array::operator+=(const int a) {
    std::function<int(int)> my_f([&a](int b) { return b + a; });
    return transform(my_f);
}
```